# Return all values in column A where column B and C meet specified criteria in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with 10 people and each person has a different number of different fruits. I want to input the exact combination of fruits and have SQL spit out the person (if they exist) who has that exact combination of fruits.

For example:

```
SELECT Person, Fruit, Number OF Fruits

WHERE Fruit1 = Orange AND Number OF Fruits = 6
AND Fruit2 = Banana AND Number OF Fruits = 3
AND Fruit3 = Apple AND Number OF Fruits = 1
```

I want this to return Adam and his Fruits and their quantities. How can I do that in SQL?  Thanks in advance.

| Person | Fruit | Number of Fruits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Apple | 5 |
| Mary | Banana | 4 |
| Mary | Orange | 1 |
| John | Banana | 3 |
| John | Kiwi | 7 |
| Adam | Orange | 6 |
| Adam | Banana | 3 |
| Adam | Apple | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE people(
> name varchar(10),
> fruit varchar(10),
> qty int);
> INSERT INTO people VALUES
> ('Mary','Apple',  5),
> ('Mary','Banana', 4),
> ('Mary','Orange', 1),
> ('John','Banana', 3),
> ('John','Kiwi',   7),
> ('Adam','Orange', 6),
> ('Adam','Banana', 3),
> ('Adam','Apple',  1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM people;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | fruit  | qty
> :--- | :----- | --:
> Mary | Apple  |   5
> Mary | Banana |   4
> Mary | Orange |   1
> John | Banana |   3
> John | Kiwi   |   7
> Adam | Orange |   6
> Adam | Banana |   3
> Adam | Apple  |   1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name FROM people
> WHERE (fruit='Orange' and qty=6)
> OR (fruit='Banana' and qty=3)
> OR (fruit='Apple' and qty=1)
> GROUP BY name
> HAVING count(fruit)=3;
> ```
>
> ```
> | name |
> | :--- |
> | Adam |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97fe8fcc501a4defae8bff378b703051)*

Comment: I'd note the count=3 in the having needs to match the number of "OR" values in where clause and it assumes a user fruit combination can't be repeated.  Of the 3 I personally like this the best.

Comment: Fails this use case: (Notice mike shows up but doesn't meet all 3 criteria) [DB FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=35a2104e6a688703d6edc7c321029335)  He just has 1 set of data repeated.  (has 2 orange records and no apple yet is included in results)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - each person has exactly 10 fruits so the fail case for Mike isn't a problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Person FROM
(
SELECT
 Person, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Orange' THEN Number_of_fruits ELSE 0 END) as cnt_orange,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Apple' THEN Number_of_fruits ELSE 0 END) as cnt_apple,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Banana' THEN Number_of_fruits ELSE 0 END) as cnt_banana,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Kiwi' THEN Number_of_fruits ELSE 0 END) as cnt_kiwi,
 ...
 sum aggregation for other fruits
 ...
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Person
) t
WHERE cnt_orange = 6 AND cnt_banana = 3 AND cnt_apple = 1
```

Comment: Pivots fruits so all on one line.  Has some overhead in terms of pivoting data & Assumes finite fruit list but works.

Comment: Thanks! I should have specified that I actually have thousands of fruits in the data base so it's not feasible to pivot each fruit but great solution for small fruit list.

Comment: no prob) ps. wow, thousands, I would barely count even a hundred, lol

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially dealing with an [Entity-Attribute-Value data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), where the person is the entity, the fruit is the attribute, and the number of fruits is the value.

To solve this, you'd want to use the normal EAV pattern of a series of self-joins., one for each attribute (fruit) you want to return.

```
SELECT t1.person, t1.fruit, t1.num_fruits, t2.fruit, t2.num_fruits, t3.fruit, t3.num_fruits
    FROM YourTable t1
        INNER JOIN YourTable t2
            ON t1.person = t2.person
                AND t2.fruit = 'banana' 
                AND t2.num_fruits = 3
        INNER JOIN YourTable t3
            ON t1.person = t3.person
                AND t3.fruit = 'apple' 
                AND t3.num_fruits = 1
    WHERE t1.fruit = 'orange' 
        AND t1.num_fruits = 6;
```

Comment: Overhead in the joins but avoids assumptions about the data and isn't very dynamic if they want n fruit evaluations.  Addresses the asked question.

Comment: Great solution that doesn't use Group By but less dynamic than the other solution since n fruit evaluations vary often for my purposes. Thanks!